# ByteArray to DoubleArray in Kotlin

Tags: java, arrays, kotlin

I want to extrapolate a byte array into a double array.

I know how to do it in Java. But the AS converter doesn't work for this... :-D

This is the class I want to write in Kotlin:

```java
class ByteArrayToDoubleArrayConverter {

    public double[] invoke(byte[] bytes) {
        double[] doubles = new double[bytes.length / 2];
        int i = 0;

        for (int n = 0; n < bytes.length; n = n + 2) {
            doubles[i] = (bytes[n] & 0xFF) | (bytes[n + 1] << 8);
            i = i + 1;
        }

        return doubles;
    }
}
```

This would be a typical example of what results are expected:

```kotlin
class ByteArrayToDoubleArrayConverterTest {

    @Test
    fun `check typical values`() {
        val bufferSize = 8
        val bytes = ByteArray(bufferSize)
        bytes[0] = 1
        bytes[1] = 0

        bytes[2] = 0
        bytes[3] = 1

        bytes[4] = 0
        bytes[5] = 2

        bytes[6] = 1
        bytes[7] = 1
        val doubles = ByteArrayToDoubleArrayConverter().invoke(bytes)
        assertTrue(1.0 == doubles[0])
        assertTrue(256.0 == doubles[1])
        assertTrue(512.0 == doubles[2])
        assertTrue(257.0 == doubles[3])
    }
}
```

Any idea? Thanks!!!

Comment: You're only doing a 16-bit conversion. Shouldn't it be a lot more for a double?

Comment: Good insight, @NomadMaker. It is for 16-bit audio. So it is OK as it is.

Comment: The problem is that you are making a 16-bit integer, which is then being implicitly cast to a double. It doesn't seem that efficient.

Comment: Actually, I am not acquainted with this type of operation. I just want to do this in Kotlin.

Comment: A style comment, instead of `val bytes = ByteArray(bufferSize) ...` you can declare and initialise in one go: `val bytes = byteArrayOf(1,0,0,1,0,2,1,1)`

Comment: Sure, @DavidSoroko. It is just for readability in tests. But thanks!! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would be clearest with a helper function.  Here's an extension function that uses a lambda to convert pairs of bytes into a DoubleArray:

```
inline fun ByteArray.mapPairsToDoubles(block: (Byte, Byte) -> Double)
    = DoubleArray(size / 2){ i -> block(this[2 * i], this[2 * i + 1]) }
```

That uses the DoubleArray constructor which takes an initialisation lambda as well as a size, so you don't need to loop through setting values after construction.

The required function then simply needs to know how to convert each pair of bytes into a double.  Though it would be more idiomatic as an extension function rather than a class:

```
fun ByteArray.toDoubleSamples() = mapPairsToDoubles{ a, b ->
    (a.toInt() and 0xFF or (b.toInt() shl 8)).toDouble()
}
```

You can then call it with e.g.:

```
bytes.toDoubleSamples()
```

(`.toXxx()` is the conventional name for a function which returns a transformed version of an object.  The standard name for this sort of function would be `toDoubleArray()`, but that normally converts *each* value to its own double; what you're doing is more specialised, so a more specialised name would avoid confusion.)

The only awkward thing there (and the reason why the direct conversion from Java fails) is that Kotlin is much more fussy about its numeric types, and won't automatically promote them the way Java and C do; it also doesn't have byte overloads for its bitwise operators.  So you need to call `toInt()` explicitly on each byte before you can call `and` and `shl`, and then call `toDouble()` on the result.

The result is code that is a lot shorter, hopefully much more readable, and also very efficient!  (No intermediate arrays or lists, and — thanks to the `inline` — not even any unnecessary function calls.)

(It's a bit more awkward than most Kotlin code, as primitive arrays aren't as well-supported as reference-based arrays — which are themselves not as well-supported as lists.  This is mainly for legacy reasons to do with Java compatibility.  But it's a shame that there's no [`chunked()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html) implementation for ByteArray, which could have avoided the helper function, though at the cost of a temporary list.)

Comment: This is a fine answer, but in my opinion the lambdas do not add anything useful and obscure the logic. Same-logic-lambda-free alternative:

`fun UByteArray.packToDoubles() : DoubleArray {
    fun toDouble(lowByte : UByte, highByte: UByte) : Double =
        (lowByte.toUInt() or (highByte.toUInt() shl 8)).toDouble()

    return DoubleArray(size / 2){ i -> toDouble(this[2 * i], this[2 * i + 1]) }
}
`

Comment: @DavidSoroko The advantage of taking a lambda is that `mapPairsToDoubles()` could be reused to do other sorts of conversion. (Even if not, the discipline of writing general functions can often help make them clearer and more focussed.) I find my version easier to read, because it more clearly separates out the logic. But there's always an element of personal taste! (It's a shame you can't properly format code in comments. Feel free to make yours a separate answer.)

Comment: mine is just a comment, no need for a separate answer. As to reusability, one can reuse the the `(byte,byte)-> double` logic by moving out the nested function. I see hiding that logic as advantage in the cases where this is a case specific implementation detail. And yes, shame about formatting.

Comment: Wonderful answer, @gidds!! :-)